# Python - Return values in a corresponding column in the value matches in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return the values in a columns when a condition matches for another column. For example:

`X` and `Y` are two columns. `X` has values `1,2,3,4,5`. and `Y` has `0,1,1,0,1`

If `Y= 0`, the code should return all the corresponding values in `X(i.e 1,4)`. And if `Y = 1`, it should return `2,3,5`.

This is the code i wrote:

```
for i in dataset:
    if y[i] == 1: 
        x1 = X.iloc[:,0]     
        print(x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use subsetting:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Y': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})

print(df.X[df.Y==0])
print(df.X[df.Y==1])
```

---

Which yields

```
0    1
3    4
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

and

```
1    2
2    3
4    5
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

This will be much faster than anything else (including custom written `for` loops).

Comment: I am using a csv file as my dataset and it does not have column headers as X and Y. Is there any way to accomplish it other than inserting headers to the dataset?

Comment: I got it. created separate variables for the columns and it worked. Thanks Jan